# WebAudio API background operation on Safari iOS 7

Tags: ios, html, audio, safari, web-audio-api

I would like to generate sounds in HTML5 and to be able to play them on background operation, I mean when the screen is off.

Right now I am able to generate sounds using ScriptProcessor of webAudio API and play them correctly on Safari/Chrome for iOS 7.

The problem is that when I turn the screen off, when using Safari, the sounds are stopped and the sound reproduction is started again when I turn the screen on. This problem does not happen in Chrome, I can listen to them even with the screen off.

Is there something I can do to support this feature in Safari?